# Karaf installation problems in ubuntu

Tags: apache-karaf

Using ubuntu 12.04 and Oracle JDK 7

Following this installation [instructions](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/quick-start.html)

I've checked the Java version requirement and the $JAVA_HOME

```
santi@one:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/home/santi/a/jdk1.7.0_60
```

I've downloaded and extracted karaf 3.0.1 from [here](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/karaf/3.0.1/apache-karaf-3.0.1.tar.gz)

When starting the server

```
santi@one:~$ cd apache-karaf-3.0.1/bin
santi@one:~/apache-karaf-3.0.1/bin$ ./start
```

What they say:

You should see the following information on the command line console:

```
        __ __                  ____
       / //_/____ __________ _/ __/
      / ,<  / __ `/ ___/ __ `/ /_
     / /| |/ /_/ / /  / /_/ / __/
    /_/ |_|\__,_/_/   \__,_/_/

  Apache Karaf (3.0.0)

Hit '<tab>' for a list of available commands
and '[cmd] --help' for help on a specific command.
Hit '<ctrl-d>' or type 'system:shutdown' or 'logout' to shutdown Karaf.

karaf@root()>
```

What I see:

```
santi@one:~/apache-karaf-3.0.1/bin$
```

What log say:

```
Jun 21, 2014 3:51:54 AM org.apache.karaf.main.lock.SimpleFileLock lock
INFO: Trying to lock /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/lock
Jun 21, 2014 3:51:54 AM org.apache.karaf.main.lock.SimpleFileLock lock
INFO: Lock acquired
Jun 21, 2014 3:51:54 AM org.apache.karaf.main.Main$KarafLockCallback lockAquired
INFO: Lock acquired. Setting startlevel to 100
2014-06-21 03:51:54,604 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/jmx.acl.org.apache.karaf.security.jmx.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,618 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/org.apache.karaf.command.acl.system.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,630 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/jmx.acl.org.apache.karaf.bundle.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,641 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/org.apache.karaf.features.repos.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,651 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,660 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/jmx.acl.java.lang.Memory.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,669 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/org.apache.felix.fileinstall-deploy.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,676 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,681 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/org.apache.karaf.command.acl.kar.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,687 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/org.apache.karaf.shell.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,694 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,702 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/org.apache.karaf.command.acl.shell.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,711 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/jmx.acl.org.apache.karaf.config.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,719 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/org.apache.karaf.jaas.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,726 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/org.apache.karaf.log.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,733 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/org.apache.karaf.features.obr.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,740 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/org.apache.karaf.command.acl.feature.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,745 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/org.apache.karaf.command.acl.jaas.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,750 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/org.apache.karaf.kar.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,756 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/jmx.acl.osgi.compendium.cm.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,762 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/org.apache.karaf.command.acl.config.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,768 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/jmx.acl.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,774 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/org.apache.karaf.command.acl.bundle.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:54,780 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Installed /home/santi/a/apache-karaf-3.0.1/etc/org.apache.karaf.management.cfg
2014-06-21 03:51:57,004 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 19 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.0 | Bundle org.apache.karaf.features.command is waiting for namespace handlers [http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/shell/v1.1.0]
2014-06-21 03:51:57,039 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 19 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.0 | Bundle org.apache.karaf.shell.console is waiting for dependencies [(objectClass=org.apache.felix.service.command.CommandProcessor), (objectClass=org.apache.felix.service.threadio.ThreadIO)]
2014-06-21 03:51:57,059 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 19 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.0 | Bundle org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules is waiting for namespace handlers [http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/jaas/v1.0.0]
2014-06-21 03:51:57,204 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 19 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.0 | Bundle org.apache.karaf.bundle.command is waiting for namespace handlers [http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/shell/v1.1.0]
2014-06-21 03:51:57,353 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 19 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.0 | Bundle org.apache.karaf.shell.help is waiting for dependencies [(objectClass=org.apache.felix.service.threadio.ThreadIO)]
2014-06-21 03:51:57,396 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 19 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.0 | Bundle org.apache.karaf.system.command is waiting for namespace handlers [http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/shell/v1.1.0]
2014-06-21 03:51:57,416 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 19 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.0 | Bundle org.apache.karaf.shell.commands is waiting for namespace handlers [http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/shell/v1.1.0]
2014-06-21 03:51:57,471 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 19 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.0 | Bundle org.apache.karaf.config.command is waiting for namespace handlers [http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/shell/v1.1.0]
2014-06-21 03:51:57,485 | INFO  | rint Extender: 1 | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 19 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.0 | Bundle org.apache.karaf.shell.console is waiting for dependencies [(objectClass=org.apache.felix.service.command.CommandProcessor)]
2014-06-21 03:51:57,689 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | SecuredCommandConfigTransformer  | 37 - org.apache.karaf.shell.console - 3.0.1 | Generating command ACL config org.apache.karaf.command.acl.kar into service ACL configs [org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.kar.install, org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.kar.uninstall]
2014-06-21 03:51:57,707 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | SecuredCommandConfigTransformer  | 37 - org.apache.karaf.shell.console - 3.0.1 | Generating command ACL config org.apache.karaf.command.acl.config into service ACL configs [org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.config.property-set, org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.config.delete, org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.config.cancel, org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.config.update, org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.config.property-delete, org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.config.property-append, org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.config.edit]
2014-06-21 03:51:57,755 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | SecuredCommandConfigTransformer  | 37 - org.apache.karaf.shell.console - 3.0.1 | Generating command ACL config org.apache.karaf.command.acl.feature into service ACL configs [org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.feature.uninstall, org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.feature.install]
2014-06-21 03:51:57,778 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | SecuredCommandConfigTransformer  | 37 - org.apache.karaf.shell.console - 3.0.1 | Generating command ACL config org.apache.karaf.command.acl.bundle into service ACL configs [org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.bundle.install, org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.bundle.uninstall, org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.bundle.update, org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.bundle.restart, org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.bundle.start, org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.bundle.stop, org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.bundle.watch, org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.bundle.refresh]
2014-06-21 03:51:57,806 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | SecuredCommandConfigTransformer  | 37 - org.apache.karaf.shell.console - 3.0.1 | Generating command ACL config org.apache.karaf.command.acl.shell into service ACL configs [org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.shell.java, org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.shell.edit, org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.shell.exec, org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.shell.new]
2014-06-21 03:51:57,817 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | SecuredCommandConfigTransformer  | 37 - org.apache.karaf.shell.console - 3.0.1 | Generating command ACL config org.apache.karaf.command.acl.system into service ACL configs [org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.system.start-level, org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.system.shutdown, org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.system.property]
2014-06-21 03:51:57,822 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | SecuredCommandConfigTransformer  | 37 - org.apache.karaf.shell.console - 3.0.1 | Generating command ACL config org.apache.karaf.command.acl.jaas into service ACL configs [org.apache.karaf.service.acl.command.jaas.update]
2014-06-21 03:51:59,391 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | RegionsPersistenceImpl           | 65 - org.apache.karaf.region.persist - 3.0.1 | Loading region digraph persistence
2014-06-21 03:52:00,076 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | SecurityUtils                    | 41 - org.apache.sshd.core - 0.9.0 | BouncyCastle not registered, using the default JCE provider
2014-06-21 03:52:01,285 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | core                             | 74 - org.apache.aries.jmx.core - 1.1.1 | Starting JMX OSGi agent
2014-06-21 03:52:01,345 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | core                             | 74 - org.apache.aries.jmx.core - 1.1.1 | Registering MBean with ObjectName [osgi.compendium:service=cm,version=1.3,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=06aa4be9-033a-494b-9616-53dfd119166e] for service with service.id [13]
2014-06-21 03:52:01,358 | INFO  | JMX OSGi Agent   | core                             | 74 - org.apache.aries.jmx.core - 1.1.1 | Registering org.osgi.jmx.service.cm.ConfigurationAdminMBean to MBeanServer com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@588980b7 with name osgi.compendium:service=cm,version=1.3,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=06aa4be9-033a-494b-9616-53dfd119166e
2014-06-21 03:52:01,359 | INFO  | JMX OSGi Agent   | core                             | 74 - org.apache.aries.jmx.core - 1.1.1 | Registering org.osgi.jmx.framework.PackageStateMBean to MBeanServer com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@588980b7 with name osgi.core:type=packageState,version=1.5,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=06aa4be9-033a-494b-9616-53dfd119166e
2014-06-21 03:52:01,360 | INFO  | JMX OSGi Agent   | core                             | 74 - org.apache.aries.jmx.core - 1.1.1 | Registering org.osgi.jmx.framework.FrameworkMBean to MBeanServer com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@588980b7 with name osgi.core:type=framework,version=1.7,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=06aa4be9-033a-494b-9616-53dfd119166e
2014-06-21 03:52:01,361 | INFO  | JMX OSGi Agent   | core                             | 74 - org.apache.aries.jmx.core - 1.1.1 | Registering org.osgi.jmx.framework.ServiceStateMBean to MBeanServer com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@588980b7 with name osgi.core:type=serviceState,version=1.7,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=06aa4be9-033a-494b-9616-53dfd119166e
2014-06-21 03:52:01,377 | INFO  | JMX OSGi Agent   | core                             | 74 - org.apache.aries.jmx.core - 1.1.1 | Registering org.osgi.jmx.framework.BundleStateMBean to MBeanServer com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@588980b7 with name osgi.core:type=bundleState,version=1.7,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=06aa4be9-033a-494b-9616-53dfd119166e
2014-06-21 03:52:01,379 | INFO  | JMX OSGi Agent   | core                             | 74 - org.apache.aries.jmx.core - 1.1.1 | Registering org.osgi.jmx.framework.wiring.BundleWiringStateMBean to MBeanServer com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@588980b7 with name osgi.core:type=wiringState,version=1.1,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=06aa4be9-033a-494b-9616-53dfd119166e
```

Comment: you should mark your answer as the answer, so that everyone knows the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, It was my fault.

I've used the start.sh script instead of karaf.sh.

start.sh uses karaf.sh with the server parameter.

The installation instructions were not so carafully followed by me as I thought

Comment: I met the similar problem with lock failed in end, your solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: @LarryCai this is probably because the container is already running (perhaps start automatically or left running from a previous manual start).